# Button: Onclick change own bgcolor

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, background-color

I have 10 buttons and when clicking one of them, the button should change its own background color to #B2DD28. -How to do this?

```
<button type="button" onClick="">time:</button>
<button type="button" onClick="">length:</button>
<button type="button" onClick="">position:</button>
```

-Is this possible in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

you can use inside this button itsef..

```
<button type="button" onClick="this.style.background = 'red'">time:</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a css style class

> .myColor {  background-color:#B2DD28; }

and add this class on click events of each button. Something like

> $(this).addClass(myColor)

Comment: need a little more code - something like <style></style> and <script></script> is missing in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly take a look at this sample I made it is written in pure Javascript not Jquery.

```html
<button type="button" onClick="changeColor(this)">time:</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeDynamicColor(this, 'blue')">length:</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeDynamicColor(this, 'green')">position:</button>


<script>

function changeColor(e){

 e.style.backgroundColor = "#B2DD28";
  
}

function changeDynamicColor(e, color){

 e.style.backgroundColor = color;
  
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/xrewf2jf/) a relatively trivial event-agnostic and self-unaware alternative way to do it, if you're so inclined... It is probably better to use a proper event handler registration model provided by JavaScript ([addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) or a framework like JQuery. :)

```js
function derp() {
  document.activeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#B2DD28';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="derp()">time:</button>
<button type="button" onclick="derp()">length:</button>
<button type="button" onclick="derp()">position:</button>
```

Just click 'Run code snippet' above and then click the buttons to see them turn the `#B2DD28` shade of green. :)